# CGridView show columns

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have a status field, which should be highlighted in green or red, depending on where 0 or 1. I have the following code, but it does not work, all the cells in a single color paint. Tell me how to do such a thing?

```
array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => $model->status == 0 ? "non_payed_status" : "payed_status"),
            'filter' => false,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override CDataColumn class, look at this, maybe will help:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/

Comment: I used this example:
`'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'$data->id', 'class'=>'"name_{$data->id}"')`
but html generate:
`<td id="$data->id" class=""name_{$data->id}"">0</td>`

Comment: you have forgot this attribute: 'evaluateHtmlOptions'=>true, on declaring column

Comment: displays an CException: Property "CDataColumn.evaluateHtmlOptions" is not defined.

Comment: you didn't add the 'class' => 'DataColumn' for this column attribute

Comment: I have forgot this attribute: 'class'=>'DataColumn',
now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with callback function.

in view - CGridView column

```html
array(
  'name' => 'status',
  'value' => array($this,'status_color'), // status_color is callback method
  'htmlOptions' => array('class' => $model->status == 0 ? "non_payed_status" : "payed_status"),
  'filter' => false,
 ),
```

In controller class

```html
public function status_color($data)
 {
  if($data->status)
  {
   echo '<div class="payed_status">Active</div>';
  }else{
   echo '<div class="non_payed_status">Inactive</div>';
  }
   return false;
 }
```

try this, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => $data->status == 0 ? "non_payed_status" : "payed_status"),
            'filter' => false,
        ),
```

Just change `$model->status` to `$data->status`. Let me know if its working.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

'type'=>'raw'

```
array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => $model->status == 0 ? "non_payed_status" :"payed_status"),
            'filter' => false,
    'type'=>'raw'
        ),
```

Comment: It did not help. All cells in one color.

Comment: This answer help me `'type'=>'raw'`